# summing splitted text from .txt file

Tags: c#

I want to summing all piece[1] in line

```
    private async void search()
    {
        if (tbs.Text != null)
        {
            var files = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(logid.Text + ".txt");
            var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(files);
            var pattern = tbs.Text;  
            foreach (string line in lines.Where(line => line.Contains(pattern)))
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

each line are something like this
income 10000 
income 20000

I want to sum all the second piece (piece[1])
how to do this?

Comment: You mean you want 30000 as result?

Comment: @SidharthMudgal yes exactly

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have list like below, you can get the sum as:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "income 10000", "income 20000", "income 30000" };
var sum = list.Sum(r => int.Parse(r.Split(' ')[1]));
```

The above assumes that you will have atleast 2 elements in the splitted array and its item on index 1 is of type integer. For the above you will get the result `60000`

If you want to use **[int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)** then:

```
var sum = list.Sum(r => { int i; 
                          return int.TryParse(r.Split(' ')[1], out i) ? i : 0; });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method to do that, using the space character for separator. It will return an array of string, the amount will be the second element.

Then you convert the string value to int with [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) to compute the sum.

```
   private async void search()
    {
        if (tbs.Text != null)
        {
            var files = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(logid.Text + ".txt");
            var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(files);
            var pattern = tbs.Text;  
            var sum = 0;
            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                var elements = line.Split(' ');
                int value;
                if (int.TryParse(elements[1], out value))
                {
                    sum += value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```